# add remove class to all buttons less the one clicked with jquery

Tags: jquery, class

I have a div with several buttons like this:

```
  <div id="HorasF">
       <input type="text" class="DTE_Field_Type_text" id="horaF" />
       <input type="button" id="h1" class="btn btn-primary btn-smallD" value="13:00" />
       <input type="button" id="h2" class="btn btn-primary btn-smallD" value="13:30" />
       <input type="button" id="h3" class="btn btn-primary btn-smallD" value="13:45" />
       //several more       
      </div>
```

So What I'm trying to do is when a button is pressed it changes its own class:

```
  $(this).removeClass('btn-smallD').addClass('btn-small');});
```

What I need is to change all other buttons class to prevent two buttons to have the same class.
Is there some kind of loop to do it? I've read also about [.siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) but I'm not getting the point for use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed use **[`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** for this.

```
$(this)
    .removeClass('btn-smallD').addClass('btn-small')
    .siblings('[type="button"]')
        .removeClass('btn-small').addClass('btn-smallD');
```